# ¿Qué lenguaje de programación es el que se utiliza en archivos batch (.bat)?

Tags: windows, archivo, cmd, batch

¿Que lenguaje de programación es el que se utiliza en archivos batch (.bat) de Windows? Yo pensaba que era ms-dos, pero ms-dos tengo entendido que es el sistema operativo. Pensaba que era bat pero es la extensión del archivo. Pensaba después que era batch pero archivo batch es un archivo de procesamiento por lotes. Y por último estaba con la idea de cmd pero cmd es la consola.

Así que si quiero buscar por internet por ejemplo como programar tal cosa, ¿como debería buscar? Por ejemplo, para abrir una aplicación, ¿lo correcto como sería? "Como abrir aplicacion con...", bat? cmd? ms-dos?

No se si me explico.

¿El lenguaje de programación para programar ejecutables de Windows cual es?

Saludos.

Comment: En DOS, OS/2 y Microsoft Windows un archivo batch es un archivo de procesamiento por lotes. Se trata de archivos de texto sin formato, guardados con la extensión BAT que contienen un conjunto de comandos MS-DOS.
Para buscar en internet algo así pues yo pondría crear ejecutables .bat
Mirate esto que tiene algún ejemplo:
https://norfipc.com/utiles/tutorialbatch1.html

Comment: Por lo que he podido ver la denominación adecuada sería **DOS Batch Script** o también **scripts in batch (.bat) files**. Lo he puesto en inglés porque para buscarlo en internet va a ver más práctico. En español sería algo así **Script por lotes para DOS** o bien **scripts por lotes en ficheros .bat**.

Comment: En el caso de los sistemas operativos Windows los ficheros `.bat` no son más que una serie de órdenes en formato MS-DOS que el sistema operativo acepta. MS-DOS fue el sistema operativo sin interfaz gráfica de Microsoft durante bastantes años, por lo que era necesario una serie de comandos para poder interactuar con éste. Como aclaración, en un principio Windows no fue más que la interfaz gráfica para este SO, aunque actualmente esto ya no es así, Windows es el nombre de todo el conjunto y MS-DOS está descontinuado, aunque los comandos con los que se interactúa con Windows son los mismos. A tu